# Yahoo Pipes Using Regex to change link

Tags: regex, url, hyperlink, pipe, yahoo

Hi I am pretty new to regex I can do some basic functions but having trouble with this. I need to change the link in the rss feed.

I have a url like this:
http://mysite.test/Search/PropDetail.aspx?id=38464&id=38464&listingid=129-2-6430678&searchID=250554873&ResultsType=SearchResult

and want to change it to updated site:

http://mysite.test/PropertyDetail/?id=38464&id=38464&listingid=129-2-6430678&searchID=250554873&ResultsType=SearchResult

Where only thing changed is from /Search/PropDetail.aspx
to /PropertyDetail/

I don't have access to the orginal rss feed or I would change it there so I have to use pipes. Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex control.

In it, specify the DOM address of the node containing your link (prefixed by "item.") within the "In" field.  For the "replace" field type

```
(.*)//Search//PropDetail/.aspx
```

and in the "with" field type use:

```
$1//PropertyDetail//.*
```

I've 'escaped' the '/' character in the with field.  However, I'm not sure you need to do this except before the '.*' Some trial and error may be needed.

Hopefully this will achieve the result you want.